# Snowflake- Cloud data platform - How to select all columns from external staged file

Tags: external, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a file staged in external S3 and want to select all the columns in the select statement.

Comment: Have you tried select  *

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing source code enables members to offer more specific advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if your stage name is stage1_stage and there are 4 columns in the file, you can list the data using a query as below

```
SELECT $1,$2,$3,$4 FROM @stage1_stage
```

[image]